# Fields labels from gravity forms not visible

Tags: forms, gravity

I added the code to my *functions.php*

`add_filter( 'gform_enable_field_label_visibility_settings', '__return_true' );`

Now i don't like the outcome and would like to get my field labels back. I removed the code from the file and found out that my field labels still aren't visible.

*Anyone in here knows the answer to this problem?*

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Just add

remove_filter( 'gform_enable_field_label_visibility_settings', 'filter_gform_enable_field_label_visibility_settings', 10, 1 );

to remove the hook callback in your function.php file